# How to map data on CSV to web pages?

Tags: database, mysql, table, csv

Like Contact information, descriptions, budget, prices, other numbers, on a CSV or spreadsheet, how to link it to WordPress web page? I'm using cpanel, WordPress, Tablepress plugin, elementor page builder.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you're trying to achieve? You can paste WordPress URLs straight into the CSV, but it sounds like you may be trying to achieve something different.

Comment: control what information or text is displayed on the web page through an excel sheet.

Comment: You could look into some import plugins. There are some that will import a CSV file to WP and generate content based on them. You would just need to look at your specific chosen plugin to determine what columns you would need to populate.